# Automating Data Entry into VMS with E-Term32

Tags: excel, ole, data-entry, openvms, vms

I've been asked to figure out a way to do this, so please fill me in on whether this is even possible or if it shouldn't be done.

---

The goal is to automate data entry into VMS (we use E-Term32 for connecting to VMS). Things that have been discussed for this purpose: Excel spreadsheets, Dynamic Data Exchange, the macro tools available in E-Term32 (Emulation Command Language - ECL), OLE Automation, etc.

The envisioned process would go like:

1. Receive Excel file (or other data format like a text file)
2. Connect to VMS
3. Run Macro
4. Macro navigates the menu system and uses data from Excel file to enter data

---

I know there are "better" or easier ways to do this like building an application to enter the data, but my supervisors are concerned about circumventing the business logic built into the "Blue Screen" menu/applications. They are also sticklers on building new applications for stuff like this anyways.

Answer (score 1):

How is the data stored on OpenVMS, may we assume in native RMS (indexed) files? or some database (RDB, Oracle, Adabas,...) ?

Whichever, it is sure to be perfectly possible to write directly in the datastore through some ODBC or JDBC method. Freeware, or commercial (ConnX, Attunity,...). Just google: OpenVMS ODBC

Once you find a method for direct data access one should indeed be concerned about the business logic. Field formatting, values ranges, foreign keys,... 
Thus access can only be granted to (software managed by) trusted team players.
But that can be perfectly manageable and you may find the new method can be made more robust than those green-screen apps.

If direct data access is no negotiable, then there are still many options.
Screen-scrapers have been build, you should not attempt to write from scratch.

Check out commercial terminal-centric modernization tools like: http://www.rocketsoftware.com/products/rocket-legasuite-gui

presentation: http://de.openvms.org/Spring2009/03-Dutch_Police_FINAL.pdf
(I am not associated with the fine folks @ Rocket, it is just one example I am aware of. There are surely more (commercial) options.

Now about those business rules. How clean is this implement? 
Strict form/function seperation? Probably not, otherwise you would not be asking.

There are several RPC, GSOAP, methods available, free and for fee, that allow one to call OpenVMS service routines, passing in external data. That's probably the best path forward.

The company I work for, Attunity,  sells such 'legacy adapter' tools in addition to ODBC/JDBC data access to files directly.
For example, using Attunity Connect software you can connect a row in a table, to the call of a subroutine. The basic plan would be to just use an SQL INSERT statement on Linux or Windows to an ODBC datasource which is connected to an OpenVMS target. The connect software will then call an OpenVMS subroutine in a shareable library to process the row, using or at least re-using the existing business logic for validation, normalization or de-normalization as the case might be. And yes, they can also expose a SELECT or MODIFY for lookups that are more complex than can be described in SQL. 
Everybody happy! You can use modern tools, they can use the old code and checks.

And ofcourse another time-honored method is to just have an FTP drop point for data to be entered. Some OpenVMS job scans an agreed upon directory for 'action' files, and runs an OpenVMS program to process the data in the fashion similar to the terminal UI app. Cobol, Basic, re-using as much of the existing terminal code and logic as possible

Good luck!
Hein